# Why doesnt the google firebase testlab emulators have phone numbers?

Tags: firebase, android-emulator, firebase-test-lab

When I run my app test on the test lab, I some emulators have phone numbers and others do not. I know this because I built an app to test the phone number of the users when given permission.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually just the physical devices. The virtual emulators are given phone numbers.